# Please define the agile concept of core hours

Tags: agile

I'm in a new contract where they seem to have gone overboard with Agile, including hiring a consultant merely for facilitating Agile processes.  Something he is instituting is a notion of "core hours" where we will all actually be in the same room together.  Is this really what "core hours" constitutes?  I ask because it's highly inconvenient to pick up my laptop and go to this shared location for half the day; I always thought "core hours" meant you were available, not necessarily in the same room, from 9:30 to 4, for instance.

Comment: When I asked this question I never mentioned how tiny the conference room that this consultant insisted about 8 of us get jammed into, but 5 years later I feel compelled to comment on my first ever SO question with a Dilbert cartoon: http://media.zenfs.com/en_us/News/ucomics.com/dt130803.gif

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because such questions should be asked at https://pm.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @OlivierPons Yeah what was I thinking 9 years ago, I should have known to ask on a then non-existent StackExchange site

Comment: I've been asked if I should close this question... by SO bots. I'm sorry if I sound rude... I think it's not hard to copy-paste this question at the right place, because it shouldn't be there IMHO. I hope one day they'll create a way of "moving" questions.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes and no.

Core hours are the period(s) when all team members commit to working on the project (and not doing administrative stuff or other projects). For many teams, this will imply being in the same room, but with proper planning and the necessary infrastructure, the team can work well from different locations.

Answer (score 2):

I think what you have is an extension of the "core hours" where you are.  The idea of being in the shared location is that ad-hoc meetings could occur as well as possibly being within earshot of various discussions so that you can jump in if it is something where you think your opinion or knowledge would be useful, e.g. why was this coded like that? or why do we have this requirement? kind of thing.

Answer (score 2):

I'd like to think that I'm up to date on the Agile world. In reality I am not. With that being said, I'm not so sure this is an agile concept but rather a convenient way for the team to collaborate. It sounds more like something out of *Peopleware*.

As goes with any team and trying something new, one, there will be resistance to change and two, the team should really have buy in to the new process and working methodology. The Agile consultant shouldn't just be barking orders of what you need to do. He should also be explaining and convincing you why this is a good thing. If you already think the company has gone "overboard" then I think something is wrong. Agile is a great way to work for a many (but not all) teams and shouldn't evoke a reaction like that

Having core hours makes sense so that there is an overlap for collaboration. Having people work in a more open space, maybe 4 people per large cube instead of 1 per small cube, also helps foster collaboration. At work I can just spin my chair around and there are 2 people right there who can help me out or answer questions. However, trying to force something that is uncomfortable and inconvenient defeats the purpose.

I think it would be better to tear down the cubicle walls and rearrange the cubes to make the evirnonment more collaborative.

Answer (score 2):

Slightly off topic but won't fit in a comment:

Agile is extremely disruptive of a programmers "Normal Practices".  The word Agile means you are going to have to adapt to changes, I recommend you try to accept them and not fight, because one of adaptations is to cut out team members that cause disruptions in the team.

A consultant is virtually required for a smooth, quick transition.

If your consultant is doing it right, you should be much more unhappy than you seem.  During those core hours, none of you should have your own computer--you should be sharing a group.  If things are done right, you should be coding in a "Bullpen" without cube walls (facilitates pairing and general communication).

But there are various levels to Agile, and it's intended to be adaptable.  Many programmers have a problem with pairing, so often it isn't forced, or is just recommended.

At any rate, it sounds like your consultant is taking it pretty easy on you guys.  Try to drink the cool-aid and relax, it'll all be over soon.